# Determine thread affinity .NET for objects that don't implement ISynchronizeInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I understand that ISynchronizeInvoke is the normal way to determine if an object has thread-affinity.  But I've found objects (in Windows Forms at least) that don't implement this but still have thread affinity.  Is there a more general way to find out the affinity?

My example is System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.  This is a Control and it implements ISynchronizeInvoke and everything is hunky-dory.  It has a Nodes property that returns a TreeNodeCollection.  This collection does NOT implement ISynchronizeInvoke but it still has the same thread affinity because it's methods eventually will call methods on the parent TreeView class.

My problem is that my application has a very general purpose mechanism where a user can use the program to call arbitrary properties and methods on any .NET class, and these calls get dispersed to multiple threads behind the scenes.  The TreeViewCollection is just one example where I have no way to know if I should marshall the call to the appropriate thread.  When it comes in I just have an Object and no way to know where it came from.

So is there a more general way to determine thread affinity in this situation?

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Just make the code aware of the form object it is working with.  You don't need anything else, the controls have the same thread affinity as the form.  And better yet, only ever collect the *data* in a worker thread, don't update any controls in any other place but BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can remember the thread which registered the Object in your application and then marshal back the callback into it. You can use *System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current* to get the current synchronization context for unknown objects. There is a great chance that it will give you the wanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to determine thread affinity. ISynchronizeInvoke is not meant to be one. Sorry ;-)

There is not general way except for the documentation.

Maybe you can make your invocation code understand well-known objects in winforms (in other words, hardcode names and namespaces).